# Navigate with history.go(-1) coming from search-engines

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a problem on my wordpress-site. It's a site with much categories and sub-categories. To make it easy for the visitors, I've put a button on top with the following action `javascript:javascript:history.go(-1)`.

This is working fine, the visitor will be navigated one step back. But when my visitor comes from an search-engine, he will be send back tho that engine, off course. Is there a way to send visitors to the category one level up? Or if not, is it possible to keep people on my site and send them to the homepage? Off course this function has top work only coming from search-engines or any other visit outsite my site.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `document.referrer` to see if the previous page was from your domain. Note that this only works for navigation from links.

```
var re = /^https?:\/\/mydomain.com\//;

if (re.test(document.referrer)) {
  history.go(-1); // Only go back if the referrer is from your domain
} else {
  // Ignore, or do something else
}
```

Comment: And in else something like 

this.document.location.href = http://mydomain.html;

to navigate to the homepage?

Comment: @user2997202: Yes, if you want a specific course of action at that point, you'd put it there. So if the homepage is desired, then setting the `window.location` would work.

Comment: Can I add the function to the head of my page, or do I have to create a file for it? Now I have:

var re = /^https?:\/\/mydomain.com\//;

if (re.test(document.referrer)) {
  history.go(-1); // Only go back if the referrer is from your domain
} else {
  window.location="http://example.com”;
}    

In my current site I have the following link, how can I add the the function to it?

<a HREF="javascript:javascript:history.go(-1)">click here for one level up</a>

Comment: It  can go in the head.

Comment: And how can I add it to my href? How do I add the function?